# I am trying to create a chat event but it doesn't send message

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    messages = await channel.history(limit=3).flatten()
    await bot.wait_for('message' , check = lambda m: m.author == ctx.author)
    await ctx.send("oof")
```

So far I have came upto over here but whenever 5 messages are sent it doesn't send the message.

Remember I'm trying to make a chat event but first I'm trying out to see if it works

Comment: You can't make a new event in discord.py, events are provided as they are. Did you mean command?

Comment: Fisrtly you would have to use `on_message` event and count messages on a specific channel. Secondly you can't use `ctx.send()` because events don't take ctx parameter you would have to specifie the channel that you want to send "oof" to.

Comment: ok can i use channel.history?

Comment: so does that work now?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use "await ctx.send" in "on_message" event. You have 2 methods how you can send message:

1#
This method send message in specific channel:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!test": "<- If user type !test in chat
        channel = bot.get_channel(12345678) #<- Channel ID
        await channel.send("your message")
```

2# This method send message in channel where command is enrolling:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!test":
        await message.channel.send("oof")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I fixed it =)

Comment: No need to apologize, and thank you for taking the time to improve your answer